# Retrieving product recommendation with B2C Commerce Einstein API

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I am using B2C Commerce Einstein API https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/einstein-api/overview for salesforce commerce cloud

And I want to retrieve products recently viewed for logged in user.

```
URL: https://api.cquotient.com/v3/personalization/recs/{{einstein_id}}/recently-viewed
```

with body

```
{
"userId": "abcxxxxx"
}
```

The userId above is what i obtained when user logged in but the result is empty

```
{
    "recs": [],
    "recoUUID": "61288d10-5346-42b8-ad1c-c0dd8f38fde2"
}
```

So what is the meaning of userId and how do I get that?

```
userId string
Application-provided unique identifier for logged in users (hashed).
```

This working fine with an anonymous shopper when I using cookieId instead

Answer (score -1):

You should send the email ID of the user in the field userId.
This email should be hashed with SHA-256.

Comment: What does hashing the email accomplish here? Why are you recommending it? Is this something recommended in documentation? (please link to it to support your answer if it is) Answers with more details and more explanation are generally better.